# Fetching number from JSON response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to `JMeter`, I want to fetch the `123` number from the below JSON response  and store it in a variable. And user the value for further requests.

```
 {"data":" Abcd efgh 123 successfully created","error":null,"info":null,"warn":null}
```

Can someone address to achieve it using BeanShell Postprocessor and Regular Expression Extractor or if any there is any other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression Extractor with `(\d+)` is the simpliest.

```
Reference Name: myNumber

Regular Expression: (\d+)

Template `$1$` 

Match No. `1`.
```

It will be saved in myNumber variable

Comment: I tried but could not able to achieve this . Can you share the configuration settings. Thanks a lot for reply.

Comment: Add Template $1$ Match 1

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `number`
   - Regular Expression: `(\d+) successfully created`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${number}` or `${__V(number)}` later on where required.

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Also be aware that JMeter 3.0+ comes with [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), it is not applicable for your current enquiry however if later on you will need to get the whole attribute value(s) it will be much easier to use it rather than regular expressions